# Updating jQuery Datepicker restricted dates when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there a simple way to update a jQuery Datepicker when a button is clicked? The datepicker is displayed inline, and I would like it to always be visible.

The logic flow behind this is that the user would check off certain dates and click the 'Done' button, which would update the datepicker to restrick the dates they selected.

The code below just creates the datepicker when the program opens. Should I just create a new datepicker with the restricted dates every time the user clicks the 'Done' button?

```
 $( "#calenderDiv" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText, obj){
      $('#A12').val(dateText); 
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 0)];
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQueryUI documentation states that

> By default, the datepicker calendar opens in a small overlay when the associated text field gains focus. For an inline calendar, simply attach the datepicker to a div or span.

Is your `#calenderDiv` indeed a div or a span?

---

**Edit**
Save the selected date in a variable, and inside `beforeShowDay` you check if the date in the calender that is currently being added has the same weekday as the selected day.
You would then end up with the following code:

```
var curDate;

$("#calenderDiv").datepicker({
    minDate:0,
    onSelect:function(dateText, obj) {
        $("#A12").val(dateText);
        curDate = new Date($(this).val());
        $(this).datepicker("refresh");
    },
    beforeShowDay:function(date){
        return [(typeof curDate === 'undefined' || day != curDate.getDay())];
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to have multiple days crossed out, use an array instead, push the selected weekdays onto it and later check inside `beforeShowDay` if the date is in the array.

Comment: It is a div. Example of what I am trying to do: The datepicker opens with the program with all dates being selectable. If the user checks off the checkbox 'Sunday' and clicks done, all Sundays in the datepicker become unselectable.